# Get a list of the set variables in Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

I wonder if there is a simple way to get all the currently set variables in Capistrano 3?

So if I have:

```
set :user, "deploy"
set :application, "someapp"
```

I would like to get something like:

```
all_variables # => { user: "deploy", application: "someapp", ... }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing and found `Capistrano::Configuration.env`.

```
namespace :dump do
  task :env do
    pp Capistrano::Configuration.env
  end
end
```

This should allow you to view all `:set` variables by calling `cap dump:env`.

Use `fetch` to get the values.

[Fetch mention in getting started guide](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/)

**Quick Edit:**
To get exactly what you're looking for try:

```
all_variables = Capistrano::Configuration.env.instance_eval{ @config }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works well

```
vars = Capistrano::Configuration
  .env
  .instance_eval { @variables }
  .trusted_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

For Capistrano 2, we can use variables module - ref - https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/v2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb

```
namespace :dump do
  task :variables do
    p variables.inspect
  end
end
```